# set up identity file but still can't ssh without environment variables

Tags: scp, crontab

I am trying to set up a scp job on crontab and am testing that ability through the console. The crontab doesn't import environment variables, so I'm testing this through `env -i`, but also importing the identity key through `ssh -i`.

```
env -i sh -c "ssh -i /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa box hostname"
```

However, this doesn't work, and I simply get `Permission denied (publickey)`. I think my keys are set up correctly. I have my public key appended to the remote box's authorized_key file.

On both machines, I have these set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
```

Here is the error I get in auth.log on the remote host:

```
Sep 13 21:45:13 box sshd[59109]: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method publickey remote_ip <someip> remote_port 51635 attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth] session=box:57d87369.6185
```

EDIT2:

When running...

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK="" ssh -vv -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa myuser@myhost
```

I see...

```
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc5ee0d15a0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I tried appending the file manually to authorized_keys, and later also tried ssh-copy-id. The .ssh/ directory is 700

Comment: Why do you need env. variables?

Comment: I want to block the environment variables because that's what crontab does.

Comment: And how do you authenticate normally? Does your key have passphrase?

Comment: I normally use ssh-agent forwarding when I login. But crontab won't pick this up, hence I create a keypair and am pointing to it. I get an error, that I'll update in question.

Comment: And are you able to log in using this new key pair, when you will not have the key in ssh-agent? `SSH_AUTH_SOCK="" ssh -i /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa hostname`

Comment: Doesn't work. Updated question with more into in EDIT2.

Comment: That was not intended to work, but to test whether you can connect without your `ssh-agent`.